# Windows Phone 8 XAML Editor setting variables to null at runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've been trying to add a simple TextBlock control to my Windows Phone 8 app, however once I assign it a name in the GUI XAML editor and attempt to access the control via its assigned name in the C# code at runtime I get "NullReferenceExceptions" because the variable is never set. 
I have narrowed the problem down to the PhoneApplicationPage method "FindName" i.e.

```
PhoneApplicationPage.FindName("videoName");
```

However a call like this to some of my controls (created in the GUI editor) simply return null. Has anybody had this problem and found a fix?

Regards.

The contents of the InitialiseComponent() method:

```
 public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/Youtube%20Downloader;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
        this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));
        this.TitlePanel = ((System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)(this.FindName("TitlePanel")));
        this.ContentPanel = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("ContentPanel")));
        this.videoName = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock)(this.FindName("videoName")));
        this.videoImage = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("videoImage")));
    }
```

(The videoName and videoImage controls are the ones not getting added)

The XAML code is (that the editor has generated):

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Youtube_Downloader.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="YOUTUBE DOWNLOADER" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="videoName" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" FontSize="36" FontStyle="Normal"/>
        <Image x:Name="videoImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="408" Margin="0,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: No, its failing inside InitializeComponent(). However, even if I put it after the InitializeComponent() call it still fails.

Comment: @user1963945: Right click on that method, click "go to definition", and see if there is an actual button with the name "button1" in it.  Your xaml and at least the constructor code would help.

Comment: Yep, tried that before. It is being called (not that I can step into that function as it says the symbols aren't loaded) but to no avail.

Comment: Only thing left is to pair down your xaml and code until all you're doing is creating that button and calling the method, confirm you have the issue still, then post that xaml and code here.  Other than that, there may be some other WP8 specific quirk going on here, but I'd doubt it.

Comment: I don't see `x:Name="button1"` in your xaml.  The call to `FindName` returning null is entirely appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer but I was only using a button earlier on as an example. In my actual code it is "videoName" and "videoImage" that are returning null.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that `this.videoName` is always null?

Comment: Yes, even after InitializeComponents() is called

Comment: That's very odd.  I'd suggest trying to repro in a different project.  Sounds like something isn't building correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Clean project will fix it.